# What gets called when a UISlider value changes?

Tags: objective-c, uislider

Does a method get called when a `UISlider`'s `value` changes?  I want to be able to update a value based on the `UISliders` value, but only when it changes.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

In IB, you can hook up an `IBAction` to the `Value Changed event` or in code add target/action for `UIControlEventValueChanged`. For example:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);
}
```

Note that if you want the value change events as the user is `sliding`, then be sure that the `slider`'s `continuous property` is also set.  On the other hand, if you don't want the event to fire as the user is `sliding` and only when they finish sliding, set continuous to NO (or uncheck in IB).

Answer (score 10):

For Swift 3

```
//There is your slider
@IBOutlet weak var mSlider: UISlider!

//add a target on your slider on your viewDidLoad for example
self.mSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.onLuminosityChange), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

//callback called when value change
func onLuminosityChange(){
    let value = self.mSlider.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *prgs;

- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;


ViewController.m

- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender 
{

    self.prgs.progress=self.slider1.value;

    self.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
self.slider1.value];

}
```

Comment: Hi Acharya, welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Can you please edit your answer to describe how this solves the OP's problem? Code-only answers are discouraged here. Thanks!