# iPhone: How to know UISlider is sliding or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uislider

I'm using the following code to know a slider is now sliding or not.
But is there a property or method to know that more easily?

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];            
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void)touchDown {
    self.sliding = YES;
}

-(void)touchUp {
    self.sliding = NO;
}
```

Comment: if you want to know whether the value of the slider changed or not (sliding or not), you can listen to UIControlEventValueChanged -- here's an example I found on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093143/what-gets-called-when-a-uislider-value-changes

Comment: thank you. but I know that event. I'm using slider for volume. And I also use volume changed notification. 
I want to ignore the notification while I'm sliding volume slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)touchDown { self.sliding = YES; }
- (void)touchUp   { self.sliding = NO;  }
```

Using booleans is indeed the common way to track user interaction on sliders.

> But is there a property or method to know that more easily?

No, not as far I'm aware.

Answer (score 5):

There is a property you can use.

```
slider.highlighted
```

This property will have value YES when you are holding it down.

Comment: RIGHT. `UISlider` is a subclass of UIControl, like UIButton. Very interesting