# How to implement uislider so that it can be used as a scrubber in AVQueueplayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avqueueplayer

I have implemented scrubbing using UISlider the problem is when the song is being played the slider doesnt initiate automatically ,it starts moving only when i tap on it and when the next song starts playing it moves automatically . i want the slider to move when the song starts playing ,this is the code which i am using and one more thing when i move the slider the song has to fast forward .I have added the code which i have written .can anyone help me out .Thanks

```
-(IBAction)slider:(id)sender

{
    CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);
    self.playbackObserver = [myPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_current_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
        CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale (myPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration, myPlayer.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
        if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0) {
            double normalizedTime = (double) myPlayer.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
            self.timeSlider.value = normalizedTime;
        }
        Float64 currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(myPlayer.currentTime);
        int mins = currentSeconds/60.0;
        int secs = fmodf(currentSeconds, 60.0);
        NSString *minsString = mins < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", mins] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mins];
        NSString *secsString = secs < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", secs] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secs];
        currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", minsString, secsString];

    }];

}
```

---

**EDIT**

can u explain where am i going wrong

```
-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
 CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);
    self.playbackObserver = [myPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_current_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time)
                             {
                                 CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale (myPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration, myPlayer.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
                                 if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0) {
                                     double normalizedTime = (double) myPlayer.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
                                     self.timeSlider.value = normalizedTime;

                                 }

                             }];
    [myPlayer play];

   }


-(IBAction)slider:(id)sender

{
        Float64 currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(myPlayer.currentTime);
        int mins = currentSeconds/60.0;
        int secs = fmodf(currentSeconds, 60.0);
        NSString *minsString = mins < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", mins] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mins];
        NSString *secsString = secs < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", secs] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secs];
        currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", minsString, secsString];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observer is being called when you tap on the uislider. This is why you have to tap on the slider first. Move the observer outside of the `IBAction` and possibly put it in the method that is run when the song starts.

```
-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
 CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);
    self.playbackObserver = [myPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_current_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time)
                             {
                                 CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale (myPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration, myPlayer.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
                                 if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0) {
                                     double normalizedTime = (double) myPlayer.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
                                     self.timeSlider.value = normalizedTime;

                                 }
                [self slider:nil];
                             }];
    [myPlayer play];

}
```

Or your can look at this answer [What gets called when a UISlider value changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093143/what-gets-called-when-a-uislider-value-changes) and setup the valueChange as an observer.

Comment: @orgami what does your new code look like? Edit your original post.

Comment: Bot i edited my code , whati t does is .the slider keeps moving but the duration of the song doesnt increase and when i try to drag the slider the slider doesnt move

Comment: @orgami see update answer. This will resolve your original problem of the slider not updating. Your issue with not being able to drag the slider should be a different question.